# Dictionary<int,string> Remove last item

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Ok I'm being dense.

How do I remove the last item in a dictionary?

I have code that checks for the number in the dictionary and ifs too many it always removes the last one to make room the for the next but I can't see a straightforward way to do it

```
if (recentDic.Count>= recentItemLimit )
  recentDic.RemoveAt(recentDic.Count-1)

recentDic.Add(i,someString);
```

**UPDATE:** Thanks for the comments, you learn something everyday. I have moved over to a OrderedDictionay and am now using RemoveAt

Comment: What do you mean remove the last item in a dictionary? A Dictionary isn't sorted, so you are just going to remove whatever there is in the last bucket?

Comment: What do u mean by last? Last added, first added or maybe last key - the one with greates value?

Comment: If your int represents index(or order) so you should remove item with biggest key.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Dictionary doesn't keep any order of its elements and therefore there is no way to know what a last one means.

If you want to remove a random one you can do something like what @Richard said:

```
dict.Remove(dict.Keys.Last());
```

or

```
dict.Remove(dict.Keys.First());
```

Comment: Can anyone clarify this syntax, as it does not work for me in VS 2015 and .NET 4.0?

Answer (score 4):

As @fiver notes: there is no order to a Dictionary so "last item" doesn't really make sense.

However you can get something that looks like "last":

```
dict.Remove(dict.Keys.Last());
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
recentDic.Remove(d.Last().Key);
```

Answer (score 0):

this?

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dictionary.Remove(dictionary /* .OrderBy(o => o.Value) */ .Last().Key);
```

Answer (score 0):

But if you want to remove somekind of element based on some order, try using the [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx). Then you can remove the last key by using `dict.Remove(dict.Keys.Last())`, as noted by others.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your way

```
 Dictionary<int, string> recentDic=new Dictionary<int,string>();
            recentDic.Add(1,"vijay");
            recentDic.Add(2,"ajay");

            if (recentDic.Count >= 2)
            {
                int last = recentDic.Keys.Last();
                recentDic.Remove(last);
                recentDic.Add(last, "rahul");

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If "last" is meant in a temporal way, you can keep a reference to the last inserted key and remove that one.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of future readers, some corrections to the above misinformation:

1. The order of a dictionary is **ALWAYS** the order in which each item was added. It is a fallacy that there is no order to a dictionary. The order is not random, and is completely predictable.
2. The order of a dictionary can be accessed and modified using [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) as `Petar Ivanov` explained above. If it does not work for you (like it did not work for Derf Skren) Ensure you add `using System.Linq;` in your `using` tags.